# Lock a controller method for a specific user id

Tags: go, locking, goroutine

I am using Go to build an POST API that does the following:

1. It takes a user request do some checks on the request and proceed to do some costly operations on the request.
2. The user does not care whether the operation is a success or failure, so I am doing this operation on a separate goroutine, but respond back immediately to the user, while the new goroutine does the task in the background (let's assume it takes 5-6 seconds to finish the operation).
3. The chances of user calling this API again in 5-6 seconds is very slim, but if there is a chance then there are potential logical fallacy on my operation. Basically saying, the user should only be able to call the API once the previous API operation is finished (either success or failure)
4. Other different users can still call the API by this time

So I should restrict the same user from calling the API until the process is over.
The request contains access token through which I could get the user id of the requested user.

What are the possible solutions I could consider here to implement this solution?

Things I have already considered are:

1. Simple hash map -> key being the user id and once the operation is over delete the key value pair
2. a key lock unlock mechanism -> locking based on the user id, need to explore more

is there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests an actual data race, are you sure you identified a real problem and not just an imagined one? Are the goroutines writing to the same memory location? And are you aware that the go toolkit does provide a race detector?

Comment: The goroutines basically do some database entries after some processing of the request body from a user. 
I don't have to have two entries from the same user in a period of 5 seconds

Comment: Databases in general can handle concurrent access just fine, so unless you're using some second-rate db your worry is unwarranted.